# How to set header data in a Qt QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: qt

There is a `setHeaderData` function in Qt `QAbstractItemModel`. Can any events make the function to be called to set the header data, such as the F2 key or a mouse double click?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can create a slot that is connected to a "double click" signal and call your model instance *setHeaderData* //if you overridden that function in your own model type you need to emit headerDataChanged signal, see [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemmodel.html#setHeaderData)